# JSON Deserialize is crashing due to missing properties

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, json.net

I am working in Blazor server app (.Net v6). I have an object that I am serializing and storing in the session to be retrieved by another page.  I started off with a straight-up `Storage.SetAsync("request", myObject).ConfigureAwait(false);`.  That failed for a `Self referencing loop detected` error.  So I converted it prior to saving in the session so I can set `ReferenceLoopHanding.Ignore`.

```
   var requestToJson = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(_request, Formatting.None,
       new JsonSerializerSettings()
       {
         ReferenceLoopHandling = ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore
       });

   await Storage.SetAsync("request", requestToJson).ConfigureAwait(false);
```

The serialization completes without error.  But when I try and deserialize, the app crashes with an "access violation" error.

After some searching I found the json validation tools and my deserialize code looks like this

```
var result = await Storage.GetAsync<string>("request").ConfigureAwait(false);
var json = result.Value;

JSchemaGenerator generator = new JSchemaGenerator();
JSchema schemaGenerator = generator.Generate(typeof(RequestDetailDTO));

JObject detail = JObject.Parse(json);
IList<string> errors;
bool valid = detail.IsValid(schemaGenerator, out errors);
var jsonToRequest = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RequestDetailDTO>(json);
```

And I was able to capture the errors

[image]

Here is the object I'm serializing

```
    public class RequestDetailDTO
    {
        public int RequestId { get; set; }
        public string Justification { get; set; } = string.Empty;
        public string SubmitUser { get; set; } = string.Empty;
        public DateTime SubmitDate { get; set; }
        public string? ModifyUser { get; set; } = string.Empty;
        public DateTime? ModifyDate { get; set; }
        [JsonIgnore]
        public string CurrentStatus 
        {
            get
            {
                if (Statuses.Any())
                {
                    return Statuses.MaxBy(x => x.RequestStatusTypeId).RequestStatusType.RequestStatusTypeName;
                }
                return string.Empty;
            }
            set => CurrentStatus = value; 
        }
        public virtual List<ChangeDetailDTO> ChangeDetail { get; set; } = new List<ChangeDetailDTO>();
        public virtual List<Status> Statuses { get; set; } = new List<Status>();
        public int RequestTypeId { get; set; }
        public virtual RequestType RequestType { get; set; } = new RequestType();

    }
```

Here is the output of the serialization action.

```
{
   "RequestId":12507,
   "Justification":"Adding 3 additional L5 categories under Employee Resignation Management so teams can more easily track the volumes of three core scenarios: bonus recovery  escalations relating to asset returns and exit interview support.",
   "SubmitUser":"Ethel Jones",
   "SubmitDate":"2023-05-26T00:00:00",
   "ModifyUser":null,
   "ModifyDate":null,
   "CurrentStatus":"Approved",
   "ChangeDetail":[ + ],
   "Statuses":[
      {
         "StatusId":1279,
         "RequestId":12507,
         "SubmitUser":" \r",
         "StatusDate":"2023-05-26T00:00:00",
         "Requests":[
            {
               "RequestId":12507,
               "Justification":"Adding 3 additional L5 categories under Employee Resignation Management so teams can more easily track the volumes of three core scenarios: bonus recovery  escalations relating to asset returns and exit interview support.",
               "SubmitUser":"Ethel Jones",
               "SubmitDate":"2023-05-26T00:00:00",
               "ModifyUser":null,
               "ModifyDate":null,
               "ChangeDetail":[
                  {
                     "ChangeDetailId":2442,
                     "RequestId":12507,
                     "CurrentL1":"HR Consulting",
                     "CurrentL2":"Movements",
                     "CurrentL3":"Voluntary Exit Management",
                     "CurrentL4":"Employee Resignation Management",
                     "CurrentL5":null,
                     "NewL1":"HR Consulting",
                     "NewL2":"Movements",
                     "NewL3":"Voluntary Exit Management",
                     "NewL4":"Employee Resignation Management",
                     "NewL5":"Exit Interview Support",
                     "SubmitUser":"Ethel Jones\r",
                     "SubmitDate":"2023-05-26T00:00:00",
                     "ModifyUser":"",
                     "ModifyDate":null
                  }
               ],
               "Statuses":[
                  
               ],
               "RequestTypeId":1,
               "RequestType":{
                  "RequestTypeId":1,
                  "RequestTypeName":"New",
                  "Requests":[
                     
                  ]
               }
            }
         ],
         "RequestStatusTypeId":4,
         "RequestStatusType":{
            "RequestStatusTypeId":4,
            "RequestStatusTypeName":"Approved",
            "Statuses":[
               
            ]
         }
      }
   ],
   "RequestTypeId":0,
   "RequestType":{
      "RequestTypeId":1,
      "RequestTypeName":"New",
      "Requests":[
         {
            "RequestId":12507,
            "Justification":"Adding 3 additional L5 categories under Employee Resignation Management so teams can more easily track the volumes of three core scenarios: bonus recovery  escalations relating to asset returns and exit interview support.",
            "SubmitUser":"Ethel Jones",
            "SubmitDate":"2023-05-26T00:00:00",
            "ModifyUser":null,
            "ModifyDate":null,
            "ChangeDetail":[
               {
                  "ChangeDetailId":2442,
                  "RequestId":12507,
                  "CurrentL1":"HR Consulting",
                  "CurrentL2":"Movements",
                  "CurrentL3":"Voluntary Exit Management",
                  "CurrentL4":"Employee Resignation Management",
                  "CurrentL5":null,
                  "NewL1":"HR Consulting",
                  "NewL2":"Movements",
                  "NewL3":"Voluntary Exit Management",
                  "NewL4":"Employee Resignation Management",
                  "NewL5":"Exit Interview Support",
                  "SubmitUser":"Ethel Jones\r",
                  "SubmitDate":"2023-05-26T00:00:00",
                  "ModifyUser":"",
                  "ModifyDate":null
               }
            ],
            "Statuses":[
               {
                  "StatusId":1279,
                  "RequestId":12507,
                  "SubmitUser":" \r",
                  "StatusDate":"2023-05-26T00:00:00",
                  "Requests":[
                     
                  ],
                  "RequestStatusTypeId":4,
                  "RequestStatusType":{
                     "RequestStatusTypeId":4,
                     "RequestStatusTypeName":"Approved",
                     "Statuses":[
                        
                     ]
                  }
               }
            ],
            "RequestTypeId":1
         }
      ]
   }
}
```

Here is the output of the deserialize action.  It seems to be dropping data, which accounts for the errors.

```
 {
   "RequestId":12507,
   "Justification":"Adding 3 additional L5 categories under Employee Resignation Management so teams can more easily track the volumes of three core scenarios: bonus recovery  escalations relating to asset returns and exit interview support.",
   "SubmitUser":"Ethel Jones",
   "SubmitDate":"2023-05-26T00:00:00",
   "ModifyUser":null,
   "ModifyDate":null,
   "CurrentStatus":"Approved",
   "ChangeDetail":[
    ],
   "Statuses":[
      {
         "StatusId":1279,
         "RequestId":12507,
         "SubmitUser":" \r",
         "StatusDate":"2023-05-26T00:00:00",
         "Requests":[
            {
               "RequestId":12507,
               "Justification":"Adding 3 additional L5 categories under Employee Resignation Management so teams can more easily track the volumes of three core scenarios: bonus recovery  escalations relating to asset returns and exit interview support.",
               "SubmitUser":"Ethel Jones",
               "SubmitDate":"2023-05-26T00:00:00",
               "ModifyUser":null,
               "ModifyDate":null,
               "ChangeDetail":[
                    {
************I think this is the first error**************
                    }
                ],
               "Statuses":[
                ],
               "RequestTypeId":1,
               "RequestType":{
************I this this is the second and third errors***********
                }
            }
         ],
         "RequestStatusTypeId":4,
         "RequestStatusType":{
            }
      }
   ],
   "RequestTypeId":0,
   "RequestType":{
        }
}
```

Sorry for all the JSON pasting, but I think its the Reference Loop Handling that is causing the missing data.  In my Request model, it has the Status object in it, which has the Request object in it, and so on; hence the Reference Loops.

Why is that, you ask?  Its because of the way I created my models in the db context. I'm still pretty new to writing these so I may have made a grievous error.

```
    // this is a 1:N - Requests and RequestType
    modelBuilder.Entity<Request>()
        .HasOne(x => x.RequestType)
        .WithMany(x => x.Requests);

     // this is a 1:N - Requests and ChangeDetail
     modelBuilder.Entity<Request>()
        .HasMany(x => x.ChangeDetail)
        .WithOne(x => x.Request);

     // this is a N:N - Requests and Status
     modelBuilder.Entity<Request>()
        .HasMany(x => x.Statuses)
        .WithMany(x => x.Requests);

     // this is a 1:N - Status and RequestStatusType
     modelBuilder.Entity<Status>()
         .HasOne(x => x.RequestStatusType)
         .WithMany(x => x.Statuses);
```

Comment: When you serialize and de-serialize this data where is it going to and coming back from?

Comment: @StevePy I'm storing it in session memory.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The crux of the issue you are encountering is that you are confusing Entities with DTOs. A DTO, or Data Transfer Object, should be a simple POCO (Plain old C# object) who's sole purpose is to relay information between layers/systems. Entities are what EF will use to express data/domain state. This means that a DTO's concern is solely the "shape" of data you want to send and return between layers and systems while an Entity reflects data state behind the scenes. An Entity's concern is the shape of the underlying domain for your system. Ultimately, the data structure in the database.

So in your entity definitions you have bi-directional references between your RequestDetail and your Status. Since a Status contains a collection of RequestDetails you first encountered a cycle warning as a request would serialize statuses which would serialize requests which would serialize statuses.......  You can stop the serialization from getting caught in that loop, but when you tell the de-serializer to re-saturate your entities that are expecting those collections, it is failing because it cannot populate them.

The solution is to differentiate entities which can have bi-directional references, with DTOs suited to being serialized. To put it simply, The Entity's concern is the shape and relations when interacting with the database. The DTO's concern is the shape of the JSON. So in your case your current "DTO" objects should be relabeled to remove the "DTO" to serve as entities with the current relationships. Then create DTO classes based on the JSON you want. The key difference of the DTO is that these classes will not have bi-directional references back to their parent associations. They can also be streamlined to contain only the data that is needed in the JSON rather than having to use `[JsonIgnore]`. Populating these DTOs from entities is referred to as Projection and can be done using `.Select()` or with Automapper and it's `ProjectTo<TDTO>()` method. `ProjectTo` is recommended rather than using `.Map()` as it works with `IQueryable` to shape the SQL query in the same way that `Select()` does.

One other note is that when it comes to entities, you should initialize collections/sets, but *not* singular references. So this is good:

```
public virtual List<ChangeDetail> ChangeDetail { get; set; } = new List<ChangeDetail>();
```

Arguably better to make the setter `protected` and pluralize the name to "ChangeDetails". No code other than this initialization should ever set this collection to a new `List<T>` including if you want to remove all entities.

... but don't do this:

```
public virtual RequestType RequestType { get; set; } = new RequestType();
```

Now unfortunately .Net Core will now complain about this via the non-nullable reference not being set. We want EF to manage this via Required vs. Optional but we do want it to be Null-able so far as the entity is concerned as when loading this entity we may not want to always load a RequestType and EF can guard this with Lazy Loading as a failsafe. There are a few options to get Intellisense to shut up about the warning including:

```
public virtual RequestType RequestType { get; set; } = default!; // or null!
```

I believe you could also use the `[Required]` attribute with a null-able property:

```
[Required]
public virtual RequestType? RequestType { get; set; }
```

Personally since entities will likely have a few non-nullable fields in entities and I don't want to forget and of these individual settings and start ignoring warnings, I tend to just mark a protected default constructor to get it to shut up about all of them. :)

```
#pragma warning disable CS8618 // Non-nullable field must contain a non-null value when exiting constructor. Consider declaring as nullable.
    /// <summary>
    /// Constructor used by EF.
    /// </summary>
    protected RequestDetail()
    { }
#pragma warning restore CS8618 // Non-nullable field must contain a non-null value when exiting constructor. Consider declaring as nullable.
```

This constructor is doubly useful if you want to use constructors to initialize new entity instances with arguments as EF will need a default constructor available anyways.

That should hopefully get a handle on the serialization and deserialization issues you are seeing.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to write such a thorough answer.  I do see where I got things crossed between DTO and entity.